# Scrollbar in JEditorPane in a Rectangle

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jeditorpane

I have a JEditorPane that is inside a rectangle in a window so that it doesnt fill the whole window. However when the HTML page gets too big, it cuts it off instead of putting in a scrollbar, I know I need a JScrollpane or something, but I dont want the scrollbar on the whole window, only inside the rectangle.

Here is a snippet of my code (rweb is already defined as a Rectangle):

```
        JEditorPane web = new JEditorPane();
      web.setEditable(false);  
        try {
      web.setPage("http://www.google.com");
    }catch (IOException e) {
      web.setContentType("text/html");
      web.setText("<html>Could not load webpage</html>");
    } 
    web.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
        public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
            if(e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
                if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                    try {
                        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(e.getURL().toURI());
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    rweb = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, 600);
    web.setBorder(null);
    web.setBounds(rweb);
    window.add(web);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never add the `JEditorPane` to a `JScrollPane`.  Text components don't have scroll support by themselves.

Try using `window.add(new JScrollPane(web));` instead

Take a look at [How to use scroll panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

ps- `web.setBounds(rweb);` will only work if you are using a `null` layout and if you are, you'd be better of using a `EmptyBorder` or a layout manager that provided the ability to specify insets, like `GridBagLayout`